# JanusGraph - Warning about all vertices scan after index was created

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop3, janusgraph

I am using Janusgraph 0.2.0 and have the following vertex defined (in Python):

```
class Airport(TypedVertex):
    type = goblin.VertexProperty(goblin.String, card=Cardinality.single)
    airport_code = goblin.VertexProperty(goblin.String, 
        card=Cardinality.single)
    airport_city = goblin.VertexProperty(goblin.String, 
        card=Cardinality.single)
    airport_name = goblin.VertexProperty(goblin.String, 
        card=Cardinality.single)
    airport_region = goblin.VertexProperty(goblin.String, 
        card=Cardinality.single)
    airport_runways = goblin.VertexProperty(goblin.Integer, 
        card=Cardinality.single)
    airport_longest_runway = goblin.VertexProperty(goblin.Integer, 
        card=Cardinality.single)
    airport_elev = goblin.VertexProperty(goblin.Integer, 
        card=Cardinality.single)
    airport_country = goblin.VertexProperty(goblin.String, 
        card=Cardinality.single)
    airport_lat = goblin.VertexProperty(goblin.Float, 
        card=Cardinality.single)
    airport_long = goblin.VertexProperty(goblin.Float, 
        card=Cardinality.single)
```

I then defined an index for this node on the airport code field using the following commands (some commands were excluded to keep it short).

```
mgmt.makePropertyKey('type').dataType(String.class).cardinality(Cardinality.SINGLE).make()
mgmt.makePropertyKey('airport_city').dataType(String.class).cardinality(Cardinality.SINGLE).make()
mgmt.makePropertyKey('airport_code').dataType(String.class).cardinality(Cardinality.SINGLE).make()
mgmt.makePropertyKey('airport_country').dataType(String.class).cardinality(Cardinality.SINGLE).make()
airport_code = mgmt.getPropertyKey('airport_code')
airport_city = mgmt.getPropertyKey('airport_city')
airport_country = mgmt.getPropertyKey('airport_country')
mgmt.buildIndex('by_airport_code_unique', Vertex.class).addKey(airport_code).unique().buildCompositeIndex()
mgmt.buildIndex('by_airport_city', Vertex.class).addKey(airport_city).buildCompositeIndex()
mgmt.buildIndex('by_airport_country', Vertex.class).addKey(airport_country).buildCompositeIndex()
mgmt.awaitGraphIndexStatus(graph, 'by_airport_code_unique').call()
mgmt.awaitGraphIndexStatus(graph, 'by_airport_city').call()
mgmt.awaitGraphIndexStatus(graph, 'by_airport_country').call()
```

After the creating, I use a script to describe the :schema and I see that all the indexes are Registered:

```
| Graph Index .          | Type .    | Element          | Unique | Backing  | PropertyKey  | Status    |
|-----------------------:|:-----|:--------|:-------|:--------|:-----------|:--------|
| by_airport_code_unique | Composite | JanusGraphVertex |   true | internalindex | airport_code | REGISTERED |
| by_airport_city | Composite | JanusGraphVertex | false | internalindex | airport_city | REGISTERED |
| by_airport_country | Composite | JanusGraphVertex |  false | internalindex | airport_country | REGISTERED |
```

When I try to insert the second vertex with the same airport_code, as expected, I get an exception on constraint violation. However, if I go into the gremlin console and run a traversal to retrieve the vertices by their airport_code:

```
g.V().has('airport_code').values()
```

I get a warning: **WARN  org.janusgraph.graphdb.transaction.StandardJanusGraphTx  - Query requires iterating over all vertices [()]. For better performance, use indexes**

I had a similar problem a few weeks ago, and the issue was that I was trying to define indexes based on labels and I was told that at the time, janusgraph does not support indexes on labels. However, I don't think this is the case here. 
Any suggestions or ideas on why my index is not working or not being used? 
Thanks in advance for any help. 
--MD

Answer (score 1):

You are seeing the warning because your query does not utilize the index. A [composite index](https://docs.janusgraph.org/latest/indexes.html) is used for equality matches.

> Composite indexes are very fast and efficient but limited to equality lookups for a particular, previously-defined combination of property keys. Mixed indexes can be used for lookups on any combination of indexed keys and support multiple condition predicates in addition to equality depending on the backing index store.

In order to leverage a composite index, you need to provide the property and a value to match. For example:

```
g.V().has('airport_code', 'JFK').toList()
```

I'm not sure why the index wasn't `ENABLED` after creation, perhaps something in the steps you left out. If you create the index within the same management transaction as the property keys, it should be `ENABLED` rather than `REGISTERED`. Check out the [index lifecycle](https://github.com/JanusGraph/janusgraph/wiki/Indexing) wiki.

Comment: Hi Jason, I tried the query you suggested and although I get the vertex back, I still get the warning.   gremlin> g.V().has('airport_code', 'ATL').toList()
15:36:12 WARN  org.janusgraph.graphdb.transaction.StandardJanusGraphTx  - Query requires iterating over all vertices [(airport_code = ATL)]. For better performance, use indexes.

Comment: Did you load the data before creating the index?

Comment: No, I emptied the whole database by running janusgraph.sh /clean, ran the script to create the index and loaded the vertex.

Comment: Not sure why the index wasn't ENABLED after creation, perhaps something in the steps you left out. If you created the index within the same management transaction as the property keys, it should have been ENABLED rather than REGISTERED. Check out the [index lifecycle](https://github.com/JanusGraph/janusgraph/wiki/Indexing) wiki.

Comment: I see, the index never gets into ENABLED. Do I need to issue a comment like mgmt.updateIndex(mgmt.getGraphIndex('by_airport_code_unique'), SchemaAction.ENABLE_INDEX).get() or is it supposed to happen automatically ?

Comment: If you create the property key and index in the same management transaction, it usually goes directly to ENABLED. That command to updateIndex() would be what you would need to do otherwise. Make sure you don't have any open graph transactions when you run that command.

Comment: Many thanks. I fixed the script to commit all in the same transaction and it works now.

Comment: Jason, I have created the index on airport_code, now if I try to run the following query: g.V().property("airport_code", "ATL").fold().coalesce( __.unfold(), __.addV().property("airport_code", "ATL").property("airport_runways", 6) ).next() which I thought should update the node, is giving me unique constraint violation.  Is my query wrong ?

Comment: The beginning of your query should be `g.V().has("airport_code", "ATL").fold()...` to check/filter if the ATL vertex exists.